# Weird bug where window.location.href = "" is not working

Tags: javascript

In my Chrome extension, when I write `window.location.href = "www.google.com";`, instead of going to "www.google.com", if for example I am starting on wikipedia, it goes to "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Www.google.com". It is appending the desired destination to the current location instead of replacing it.

The same thing happens when I try doing it in the Chrome console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you need to pass the protocol information i.e. http or https try this code it works fine

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

or try

```
window.location.href = "//www.google.com";
```

if you dont have protocol information

Note if you dont put protocol information then the current url is appended with the text in the double quotes of window.location.href = "appended to url";

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

just correct your URL

Answer (score 1):

Try `http://www.google.com`. Chrome uses the default search engine, when you don't use the `http://`